Breakpoints are not per project
I have two projects in the project group that use the same units.
If I set breakpoints in one, then build and run the other, the breakpoints still apply:

Can breakpoints be active for one project only?
I only see two workarounds:

Manually disable/enable all breakpoints based on which program is
running. Not nice if you have some disabled already (typical during
debugging).
Making complicated conditional breakpoints. This makes execution
slow.

(Delphi 11, Win 32)

Breakpoints are stored in the dsk file of the active project or project group. If you want breakpoints per project, you need to open each project directly. As soon as you open a project group that one is used to store breakpoints.
